# switch case statment in C# with hex values

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I have a uint value received and perceived (in terms of use) in hex values and I want to set a switch case according to this value as in the following example:

```
uint foo=someHexValue
uint a;
switch(foo){
    case 0xFFFF : a = 0x0;break;   
    case 0xFFFE : a = 0x1;break;   
    case 0xFFFC : a = 0x2;break;
    case 0x0001 : a = 0x3;break;   
    case 0x0010 : a = 0x4;break; 
}
```

Note that the values of foo are not necessarily ordered or contains all possible values.

Can I go about it with respect to the decimal values as in:

```
uint foo=hexValue
uint a;
switch(foo){
    case 65535: a = 0x0;break;   
    case 65534: a = 0x1;break;   
    case 65532: a = 0x2;break; 
    case 1: a = 0x3;break;   
    case 16: a = 0x4;break;   
}
```

Is it possible to use hex values in switch case? Is there another approach?

Comment: Are you getting output as expected? or it gives you any error?

Comment: What is the *actual* question? Didn't the code run? The number literal has nothing to do with how `switch` works, the actual number is the same

Comment: You could have tried this twice in the time it took you to type out this question and no...it makes no difference what you use.

Comment: What's stopping you from trying? Also, there are no "hex values" in C#. Hex *literals* (e.g. `0xFFFF`) are interpreted as `int`

Comment: I cannot try it and it is hard to explain why. In short I am Converting something from another tool and have no access to a compiler at the moment.

Comment: @havakok https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: @ardila Thanks a lot!

Comment: @havakok you're welcome, but next time do remember that SO is not a coding service, nor a substitute for a compiler or a search engine (as you've probably already surmised from the votes you received)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. "Hex Values" is merely a *notation* for an integral type, which is a valid case label in a C# `switch` block.

Excepting the *follow-through* nature of a `switch` block - which you are obviating with `break` statements - the order of the case labels does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. your code will work fine.Type uint can be assigned to with HEX values. If you try to print the value of "foo" or "a" after the code has been executed, you can see that they have integer values corresponding to the HEX values you have assigned them.

And HEX values can be used in switch case statements in place of integer values. Both will work perfectly fine.